# Cost of creating boost::shared_ptr vs calling a boost::shared_ptr in an unordered_map

Tags: c++, performance, boost

Declaration of 'users' in ServerData.h

```
    static std::unordered_map<long long, boost::shared_ptr<user_object>> users;
```

What is the cost difference between using

```
    boost::shared_ptr<ServerData::user_object> user = ServerData::users[session.userid];
    session.name = user->name;//and approximately 20 other calls like this
    session.age = user->age;
```

and

```
    session.name = ServerData::users[session.userid]->name;
    session.age = ServerData::users[session.userid]->user->age;//and approximately 20 other calls like this.
```

Can you please give answers for considering 2 difference scenarios where:

1- ServerData::users.size() is between 100 - 10K

2- ServerData::users.size() is more than 1M

Comment: `users[session.userid]` performs search every time. Repeating this line is a worst kind of copypasta.

Comment: Unrelated to question: Why use `boost::shared_ptr` when you are clearly using C++11 or later which has `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @user17732522 For example `boost::shared_ptr` may store pointers to arrays which become available in `std::shared_ptr` only since C++17.

Comment: If you consider that lookup takes linear time in the worst case, it should be pretty clear which one to prefer. If you're worried about the cost of copying a `shared_ptr`, make it a reference. There's no reason to worry about that, though.

Comment: I misread initially. Are you concerned with whether the cost of copying the shared_ptr outweights the repeated lookup or what cost are you trying to compare here? If so, I would say very unlikely and it can be avoided by making `user` a reference in the first variant.

Comment: @user17732522 actually I'm not sure about it either, the only reason I'm using it is because so many people suggested it back when I first started writing my server code years ago. Apparently c++ 17 is very good, if I was not using boost's asio library, I wouldn't use it just for shared_ptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason that the second should be preferred. It searches the map for each line anew which is an expensive operation. It is only needed once.

This should be true regardless of the size of the map, since I see almost no cost benefit in the second variant at all. The only additional cost in the first variant is the `shared_ptr` copy which shouldn't matter against a hash map lookup and can be avoided by making `user` a reference in the first variant.

Comment: Yes, I was not sure about the cost of copying a shared_ptr but it turned out as I expected. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @ozandeniz *"I was not sure about the cost of copying a shared_ptr"* -- why did you not say so in the question? Instead of challenging readers to figure out what you see in the code, you should be explicit. For example, *"What is the cost difference between **making a copy of a shared pointer** using"* and *"and **looking up the map element every time**"*. Without more text in the question, I doubt others with the same question will be able to find it.

Comment: @JaMiT did you even read the header? And I even said "the difference between using these 2" in the post as well. Always feeling hesitant to ask here because of the insufferable few I stumble upon each time I ask a question here. Thankfully the others were not like you.

Comment: @ozandeniz *"did you even read the header?"* -- Header? I don't see a header. Do you mean the question title? If so, then, yes I read it, but then I disregarded it because "calling a boost::shared_ptr" does not make sense. I just refrained from calling it out because doing so did not seem useful (and because I got the impression you might be a non-native English speaker). However, if you really want to classify me among the "insufferable few", I could go into full critique mode, pointing out every little mistake with no suggestions for improvement...

Comment: @ozandeniz *"I even said 'the difference between using these 2'"* -- not quite. Instead of "these 2" you gave two code blocks to read (and never mention "copy"). That is precisely what I am suggesting an improvement to. Instead of *"What is the cost difference between using [code] and [code]"* you could have written *"What is the cost difference between **making a copy of a shared pointer** using [code] and **looking up the map element every time using** [code]."* Don't rely on code to communicate. Yes, your grammar is weak, but your English is still more understandable than interpreting code.

Answer (score 2):

You can just measure things - although in this case the results are very predictable:

> ### Note:
>
> In practice your application will pose restrictions. E.g. repeated querying the map can be a race condition. So is the optimization to hold a reference instead of copying the shared-pointer.

E.g. using [Nonius](https://github.com/libnonius/nonius):

```
#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <nonius/main.h++>
#include <random>

#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>

using Id = long long;
static constexpr auto minId             = 1'000ll;
static constexpr auto maxId             = 2'000'000ll;
static constexpr auto numExtraFields    = 18u;
static auto const     fixed_random_seed = std::random_device{}();

static auto make_idgen() {
    return std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<Id>(minId, maxId),
                     std::mt19937{fixed_random_seed});
}

namespace ServerData {
    struct user_object {
        std::string name;
        unsigned    age;
        std::array<double, numExtraFields> more_fields;
    };
} // namespace ServerData

static auto const std_users = [] {
    std::unordered_map<long long, boost::shared_ptr<ServerData::user_object>> table;
    for (Id i = minId; i <= maxId; ++i)
        table.emplace(i, boost::make_shared<ServerData::user_object>("anonymous", 12));

    return table;
}();

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("hooboy", [](nonius::chronometer cm) {
    auto users = std_users;
    auto pick  = make_idgen();
    cm.measure([&] {
        auto id = pick();
        users[id]->name = "name";
        users[id]->age  = 12 + rand() % 30;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numExtraFields; ++i)
            users[id]->more_fields[i] = i;
    });
});

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("reasonable", [](nonius::chronometer cm) {
    auto users = std_users;
    auto pick  = make_idgen();
    cm.measure([&] {
        auto sess = users[pick()];
        sess->name = "name";
        sess->age  = 12 + rand() % 30;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numExtraFields; ++i)
            sess->more_fields[i] = i;
    });
});

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("optimizing", [](nonius::chronometer cm) {
    auto users = std_users;
    auto pick  = make_idgen();
    cm.measure([&] {
        auto& sess = *users[pick()];
        sess.name = "name";
        sess.age  = 12 + rand() % 30;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numExtraFields; ++i)
            sess.more_fields[i] = i;
    });
});

static auto const boost_users = [] {
    boost::unordered_map<long long, boost::shared_ptr<ServerData::user_object>> table;
    for (Id i = minId; i <= maxId; ++i)
        table.emplace(i, boost::make_shared<ServerData::user_object>("anonymous", 12));

    return table;
}();

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("boost::unordered_map", [](nonius::chronometer cm) {
    auto users = boost_users;
    auto pick  = make_idgen();
    cm.measure([&] {
        auto& sess = *users[pick()];
        sess.name = "name";
        sess.age  = 12 + rand() % 30;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numExtraFields; ++i)
            sess.more_fields[i] = i;
    });
});
```

Prints

```
clock resolution: mean is 21.1389 ns (40960002 iterations)

benchmarking hooboy
collecting 100 samples, 45 iterations each, in estimated 2.1285 ms
mean: 700.709 ns, lb 693.765 ns, ub 710.277 ns, ci 0.95
std dev: 40.9973 ns, lb 32.3424 ns, ub 52.1336 ns, ci 0.95
found 16 outliers among 100 samples (16%)
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking reasonable
collecting 100 samples, 63 iterations each, in estimated 2.1294 ms
mean: 544.189 ns, lb 538.784 ns, ub 550.853 ns, ci 0.95
std dev: 30.5399 ns, lb 25.5757 ns, ub 37.0609 ns, ci 0.95
found 4 outliers among 100 samples (4%)
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking optimizing
collecting 100 samples, 65 iterations each, in estimated 2.1385 ms
mean: 535.605 ns, lb 529.619 ns, ub 543.946 ns, ci 0.95
std dev: 35.4216 ns, lb 27.9599 ns, ub 52.1946 ns, ci 0.95
found 3 outliers among 100 samples (3%)
variance is severely inflated by outliers

benchmarking boost::unordered_map
collecting 100 samples, 75 iterations each, in estimated 2.1075 ms
mean: 495.22 ns, lb 489.909 ns, ub 502.051 ns, ci 0.95
std dev: 30.7146 ns, lb 25.1169 ns, ub 37.8619 ns, ci 0.95
found 5 outliers among 100 samples (5%)
variance is severely inflated by outliers
```

Or in graph form (click for interactive):

[image]